# Vuetify custom slot in select

Tags: select, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I have a select which has custome item slot because of tree structure categories. It is not a big deal. Everything works but I can not set up css class for selected item in drop down.
This is the code.

```
    <v-select
        v-model="selectedCategories"
        :prepend-inner-icon="CategoriesIcon"
        :label="$t('category')"
        :placeholder="$t('category')"
        :items="categories"
        :item-props="true"
        item-title="prefixTitle"
        item-value="id"
        multiple
        class="c-select-box"
        :dirty="true"
        append-inner-icon="mdi-chevron-down"
        @update:modelValue="setCategories()"
    >
        <template v-slot:item="{ props, item }">
            <v-list-item v-bind="props" 
                         v-html="item.title"  
                         :class="{'select-item-hover': true, 'select-item-selected': selectedCategories.includes(item.id)}"  
            />
        </template>

        <template v-slot:selection="{ item, index }">
            <div>{{ removeSpaces(item.title) }}&nbsp </div>
        </template>
    </v-select>
```

If I set up select-item-selected manualy to true everything works. The definition of selectedCategories look like

```
const selectedCategories = ref([])

function setCategories() {
    console.log(selectedCategories)  // Works fine
    tenantStore.setCategories(selectedCategories.value)
}
```

Can somebody tell me please what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `item` slot prop on the item slot is the internal list item, it has a different structure than the objects you pass into VSelect's `items` prop. Among other things, it contains `title` and `value` of the item, and a reference to the original element in the `raw` property. It does not contain an `id` property, so `selectedCategories.includes(item.id)` will check for undefined.

Instead either use the original element:

```
selectedCategories.includes(item.raw.id)
```

or the `value`:

```
selectedCategories.includes(item.value)
```

Where the latter is more robust (you could change `item-value` and it still works).

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: Thank you. I missed that slot get id as value.